# executing adb shell commands as root

Tags: adb, shell, java

I am using the following command from Java and it works with my old phone

```
 adb shell svc data disable
```

But with my new phone I am required to change to root (su command) in shell before I can successfully execute `svc data disable`

Is it possible to do this in one command? I use Java's Process exec method to run this command, and I'm not how to make it work with my new phone since I am required to change the shell to root first.

Comment: On terminal emulator putting `&&` between the two commands works (second command executed only on successful completion of first). Alternatively  `;` between two commands. I don't know if it same for Java

Comment: I tried `adb shell && su` on windows command line manually but it only tries to execute `su` after I press ctrl-d, I think `su` does not get executed since the shell command has not really finished executing while we are still in shell.

Comment: found the answer on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761992/launch-a-script-as-root-through-adb

Comment: You can answer the question yourself :)